# How can I reset auto-complete dictionary for my Sony Ericsson Xperia mini pro?

Tags: auto-correct, sony-xperia-mini-pro

The stock soft keyboard on Sony Ericsson Xperia mini pro has a feature called 'Learn words' (`Settings > Language & keyboard > International Keyboard > Text input settings > Learn words`) that learns from user input and adds them to the autocorrect dictionary. Over time however this has resulted in many misspelled words also being added to my autocorrect suggestions. I want to start this over from a fresh canvas. So how do I reset my autocorrect dictionary? When I go to `Language & keyboard > User dictionary` so I'm guessing Sony Ericsson uses its own keyboard replacement with its own user dictionary store.

Comment: On my Droid, `Settings > Language & keyboard` offers a "User dictionary" option, where I can see the words I've added and edit or delete them. Has that been removed from your device?

Comment: @AlEverett That menu entry is and always has been blank.

Comment: I am looking for the same answer for the Xperia Pro. I guess it is a common issue on all Xperia phones, or at least those with a physical keyboard. Please if you find how to do it, post the answer here, I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best answer I've found so far:

> You could try clearing all data from the keyboard.
>
> `Menu>Settings>Applications>Running Applications` then tap `All`. Scroll down and find `Internation Keyboard` (if thats the one you are using) and `Clear Data`.

Source: [Sony Ericsson Support Forum](http://talk.sonyericsson.com/message/149819)

Of course, it will also set the keyboard to the original settings.

Anyway, I would like to find a way to remove some misspellings and not all the learned words, so if somebody knows how to do it, I will be glad to hear from it.

Comment: on my x10 it was Menu > Settings > Applications> Running Services > Default Input but your answer got me 99% of the way there

Comment: on my Xperia Ray (ICS) it was Menu > Settings > Apps > All > Xperia Keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Menu >settings>apps>running application>find Xperia keyboard >settings(xperia keyboard)>text input settings>my words,..choose the word you want to delete or edit,,..  Thats the step that I learned so far
,.,hope helps..

Answer (score 1):

Don't wipe everything. It is possible to delete individual words.

I have the Experia T, I and have just done this:

- Open a text
- Click to reply so the keyboard pops up
- press the 12!? button down-left corner
- Go across to the right, and click on the spanner icon
- Go in to My Words
- Hold your finger down on a word, and down the right of the screen will pop up a box next to each word
- Ticking the boxes of the ones you don't want
- Hit delete, and they all magically disappear.

Answer (score 0):

goto settings>applications> (select all) > goto user dictionary/message extention/ anything having dictionary or with the Envelop logo. go there and press Clear Data. and u r done